# Getting Error in test file with the react-router-dom v6: "Property 'history' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouterProps'."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

Main file:

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

import AuthenticationContext from './AuthenticationContext';

function OAuthCallbackRoute() {
  const { fetchToken, callbackPath, setError } = useContext(AuthenticationContext);
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname !== callbackPath) return;

    async function completeLogin(code: string, state: string) {
      if (await fetchToken(code)) navigate(decodeURIComponent(state));
    }

    const successRedirectPathRegex = /\?code=(\S+)&state=(.+)/;
    const errorRedirectPathRegex = /\?error=(\S+)&error_description=(.+)&state=(.+)/;

    const successPathMatch = location.search.match(successRedirectPathRegex);
    if (successPathMatch) {
      const [, code, state] = successPathMatch;
      completeLogin(code, decodeURIComponent(state));
    }

    const errorRedirectPathMatch = location.search.match(errorRedirectPathRegex);
    if (errorRedirectPathMatch) {
      const [, error, errorDescription] = errorRedirectPathMatch;
      setError(${error} - ${decodeURIComponent(errorDescription)});
    }
  }, [fetchToken, navigate, location, callbackPath, setError]);

  return null;
}

export default OAuthCallbackRoute;
```

Test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import { OAuthCallbackRoute } from '..';
import AuthenticationContext from '../AuthenticationContext';

const delay = async (ms: number) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });

describe('OAuthCallbackRoute', () => {
  let history: any;
  let historyReplace: any;
  let fetchToken: any;
  let setError: any;
  const originalError = global.console.error;

  beforeEach(() => {
    history = createMemoryHistory();
    global.console.error = jest.fn();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    global.console.error = originalError;
  });

  function App() {
    return (
      <AuthenticationContext.Provider
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-constructed-context-values
        value={{
          fetchToken,
          callbackPath: '/oauth',
          setError,
          authenticated: true,
          authenticating: false,
          authorize: () => {},
          logout: () => {},
          getToken: () => 'xyz',
        }}
      >
        <Router history={history}>
          <OAuthCallbackRoute />
        </Router>
      </AuthenticationContext.Provider>
    );
  }

  describe('for an OAuth callback', () => {
    describe('on successful OAuth callback', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        history.replace('/oauth?code=xyz&state=%2Ffoo');
        historyReplace = jest.spyOn(history, 'replace');
      });

      describe('on successful token fetching', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
          fetchToken = jest.fn(() => true);
        });

        it('uses the received code to fetch an auth token', () => {
          render(<App />);
          expect(fetchToken).toHaveBeenCalledWith('xyz');
        });

        it('redirects to the referrer path', async () => {
          render(<App />);
          await delay(100);
          expect(historyReplace).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/foo');
        });
      });

      describe('on failed token fetching', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
          fetchToken = jest.fn(() => false);
        });

        it('does not redirect to the referrer path', async () => {
          render(<App />);
          await delay(100);
          expect(historyReplace).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
      });
    });

    describe('on error included in callback', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        setError = jest.fn(() => true);
        history.replace(
          '/oauth?error=access_denied&error_description=Service%20not%20found&state=%2Ffoo',
        );
        historyReplace = jest.spyOn(history, 'replace');
      });

      it('does not redirect to the referrer path', async () => {
        render(<App />);
        await delay(100);
        expect(historyReplace).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      });

      it('puts the error on the context', async () => {
        render(<App />);
        expect(setError).toHaveBeenCalledWith('access_denied - Service not found');
      });
    });
  });

  describe('for a non-OAuth path', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      history.replace('/random-path');
      historyReplace = jest.spyOn(history, 'replace');
    });

    it('does not attempt to fetch a token', async () => {
      render(<App />);
      await delay(100);
      expect(fetchToken).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('does not redirect', async () => {
      render(<App />);
      await delay(100);
      expect(historyReplace).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Error:

packages/auth/src/*tests*/OAuthCallbackRoute.test.tsx:46:17 - error TS2322: Type '{ children: Element; history: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouterProps'.
Property 'history' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouterProps'.

```
46         <Router history={history}>
```

I have tried to change the history with the navigator, getting different errors.

Appreciate some solutions on the "history" Error.

Comment: I see you are using my suggested code in several of your other newer questions. Did my answer here address/resolve your question/issue in this post?

Answer (score 0):

The low-level `Router` component takes a few props, two of which are required, and none of which are `history`.

[Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/router)

> ```
> declare function Router(
>   props: RouterProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouterProps {
>   basename?: string;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   location: Partial<Location> | string; // <-- Required
>   navigationType?: NavigationType;
>   navigator: Navigator;                 // <-- Required
>   static?: boolean;
> }
> ```

This said, there's almost no reason at all to use the `Router` component. Generally you will import and use the `MemoryRouter` in your unit tests. In this case it seems you have tests that need to reference a custom history object. For this you can import and use the [`HistoryRouter`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/e4f663cec9f79150933127e53c7fdacf87eaab6e/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L828-L879) which ***does*** take a `history` prop.

```js
export interface HistoryRouterProps {
  basename?: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  future?: FutureConfig;
  history: History; // <-- custom history object
}
```

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';

import { unstable_HistoryRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import { OAuthCallbackRoute } from '..';
import AuthenticationContext from '../AuthenticationContext';

const delay = async (ms: number) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });

describe('OAuthCallbackRoute', () => {
  let history: any;
  let historyReplace: any;
  let fetchToken: any;
  let setError: any;
  const originalError = global.console.error;

  beforeEach(() => {
    history = createMemoryHistory();
    global.console.error = jest.fn();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    global.console.error = originalError;
  });

  function App() {
    return (
      <AuthenticationContext.Provider
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-constructed-context-values
        value={{
          fetchToken,
          callbackPath: '/oauth',
          setError,
          authenticated: true,
          authenticating: false,
          authorize: () => {},
          logout: () => {},
          getToken: () => 'xyz',
        }}
      >
        <Router history={history}>
          <OAuthCallbackRoute />
        </Router>
      </AuthenticationContext.Provider>
    );
  }

  describe('for an OAuth callback', () => {
    describe('on successful OAuth callback', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        history.replace('/oauth?code=xyz&state=%2Ffoo');
        historyReplace = jest.spyOn(history, 'replace');
      });

      describe('on successful token fetching', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
          fetchToken = jest.fn(() => true);
        });

        it('uses the received code to fetch an auth token', () => {
          render(<App />);
          expect(fetchToken).toHaveBeenCalledWith('xyz');
        });

        it('redirects to the referrer path', async () => {
          render(<App />);
          await delay(100);
          expect(historyReplace).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/foo');
        });
      });

      describe('on failed token fetching', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
          fetchToken = jest.fn(() => false);
        });

        it('does not redirect to the referrer path', async () => {
          render(<App />);
          await delay(100);
          expect(historyReplace).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
      });
    });

    describe('on error included in callback', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        setError = jest.fn(() => true);
        history.replace(
          '/oauth?error=access_denied&error_description=Service%20not%20found&state=%2Ffoo',
        );
        historyReplace = jest.spyOn(history, 'replace');
      });

      it('does not redirect to the referrer path', async () => {
        render(<App />);
        await delay(100);
        expect(historyReplace).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      });

      it('puts the error on the context', async () => {
        render(<App />);
        expect(setError).toHaveBeenCalledWith('access_denied - Service not found');
      });
    });
  });

  describe('for a non-OAuth path', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      history.replace('/random-path');
      historyReplace = jest.spyOn(history, 'replace');
    });

    it('does not attempt to fetch a token', async () => {
      render(<App />);
      await delay(100);
      expect(fetchToken).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('does not redirect', async () => {
      render(<App />);
      await delay(100);
      expect(historyReplace).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I am facing this error in the test file:
  `● OAuthCallbackRoute › for an OAuth callback › on successful OAuth callback › on successful token fetching › redirects to the referrer path
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)
    Expected: "/foo"
    Received: {"hash": "", "pathname": "/foo", "search": ""}, undefined, {"replace": true}
    Number of calls: 1
      70 |           render(<App />);
      71 |           await delay(100);
72 |           expect(historyReplace).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/foo');                           ^
      73 |         });
    74 |       });`

Comment: @ChinnaP Your history replace function was actually called and passed `{ hash: "", pathname: "/foo", search: "" }, undefined, { replace: true }` instead of *just* `"/foo"` it seems. The jest mock/spy might be peeking in a bit more on that function's internals.